# C# foreach over properties of objects contained within a Dictionary<String, ObjectType>

Tags: c#, collections

Is it possible to itterate directly over properties of the objects stored within a Dictionary collection in C#?

For example, I have a Dictionary called Fields of type `Dictionary<String, Field>`. The Field object has a property of Data which is of type XmlDataDocument so I would like to do something like,

```
foreach(XmlDataDocument fieldData in Fields.Values.Data){

}
```

I know it's pretty trivial since all I would need to do when itterating over Field objects instead would be,

```
XmlDataDocument fieldData = field.Data;
```

within the Field itteration however if there is a quicker way to do it I'd like to know :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C# 3.0:

```
foreach (var data in Fields.Values.Select(x => x.Data))
{
}
```

It's not any "quicker" though.

Answer (score 1):

yes, create a custom collection based on Dictionary and then add your own iterator to it...

```
   public class MyFieldCollection: Dictionary<string, Field>
   {
       public IEnumerable<XmlDataDocument> Data
       {
           foreach(Field f in this.Values)
              yield return f.Data;
       }
   }
```

Then in client code all you need to do is

```
  MyFieldCollection MFC = new MyFieldCollection();    
   foreach (XmlDataDocument doc in MFC.Data)
   {
       // DoWhatever (doc ); 
   }
```